# How to receive all 21 variables in a bluetooth module (HC-06) from android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I successfully managed to receive up to three time variables in the bluetooth module. But it doesn't receive more than three. Do I have to configure the HC-06 bluetooth module?

**Arduino code** (credits to owner)

```
String message; //string that stores the incoming message

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {//while there is data available on the serial monitor
    message+=char(Serial.read());

//store string from serial command
  }
  if(!Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.print("AT");
    if(message!="")
    {//if data is available
      Serial.println(message); //show the data
      message=""; //clear the data      
    }
  } //delay
}
```

**Android application code** (send up to 5 time variables)

```
                                sendthis="t1=";
                                sendthis+=ArraytoSend[3];
                                sendthis+="t2=";
                                sendthis+=ArraytoSend[7];
                                sendthis+="t3=";
                                sendthis+=ArraytoSend[11];
                                sendthis+="t4=";
                                sendthis+=ArraytoSend[15];
                                sendthis+="t5=";
                                sendthis+=ArraytoSend[19];
                                try {
                                    mmOutputStream.write(sendthis.getBytes());
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                }
```

I have to send until ArraytoSend[83] (increments by 4) but the module only receives up to three.

What can I do to receive all 21 variables in just one sending? Do I really need to split the sending function into 7 parts?

Here is a screenshot:

[Serial monitor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2dN.jpg)

Thank you so much

Comment: `if(!Serial.available())` is not the right way to determine the end of the message. Use something else like appending a newline or \0 to mark the actual end.